# What's the correct way to print a matrix with labels in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, nested-loops

I want to do something very simple in Django: Print a matrix as an HTML table, and add labels for the rows and columns. These are the variables in my view:

```py
matrix = np.array([
    [101, 102, 103],
    [201, 202, 203],
])
colnames = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Barf']
rownames = ['Spam', 'Eggs']
```

I want a to get a table that looks like this:

```
      Foo  Bar  Barf
Spam  101  102  103
Eggs  201  202  203
```

My template code looks like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        {% for colname in colnames %}
            <th>{{ colname }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for rowname in rownames %}{% with forloop.counter0 as rowindex %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ rowname }}</th>
            {% for colname in colnames %}{% with forloop.counter0 as colindex %}
                <td>TABLECELL</td>
            {% endwith %}{% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endwith %}{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Output for different values of TABLECELL:

`{{ rowindex }}, {{ colindex }}` --> table with the indices    :)

`{{ matrix.0.0 }}` --> table full of 101s    :)

`{{ matrix.rowindex.colindex }}` --> table with empty cells    :(

As the first two things work, it doesn't seem crazy to assume that the last one would give the intended result. My only explanation is that `rowindex` and `colindex` might be strings — and of course `int()` is among the many things that are forbidden in Django templates.

Does anyone know how I can make this work? Or ideally:
Does anyone know how this is intended to be done in Django?

EDIT 1:

It seems I have to pass the enumerated lists to the template. I provide them as `enum_colnames` and `enum_rownames`, but now I can't even execute the nested for loop:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        {% for unused_colindex, colname in enum_colnames %}
            <th>{{ colname }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for rowindex, rowname in enum_rownames %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ rowname }}</th>
            {% for doesnt_work_anyway in enum_colnames %}
                <td>You don't see me.</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This gives a table with all the `<th>`s filled with the correct labels, but no `<td>`s at all.

EDIT 2:

I found an insanely ugly "solution", which I publish here as an example of something that "works", but is clearly not an answer to my question — how this *should* be done in Django. Here it comes:

```py
derp = ['', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Barf', 'Spam', 101, 102, 103, 'Eggs', 201, 202, 203]
iderp = enumerate(derp)
```

```html
<table>
    {% for i, d in iderp %}
        {% if i < 4 %}  <!-- if top row: th -->
            {% cycle '<tr><th>' '<th>' '<th>' '<th>' %}
        {% else %}  <!-- else: td -->
            {% cycle '<tr><th>' '<td>' '<td>' '<td>' %}
        {% endif %}
            {{ d }}
        {% if i < 4 %}  <!-- if top row: th -->
            {% cycle '</th>' '</th>' '</th>' '</th></tr>' %}
        {% else %}  <!-- else: td -->
            {% cycle '</th>' '</th>' '</td>' '</td></tr>' %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Note how it can only be used for tables of this particular width. So in this form it is not even a real solution for the initial problem.

Comment: Regarding edit 2, if you use a flat list you will need to pass the number of columns to the template too. That's why I suggested a table with the same structure as the matrix. I now added a suggestion on how to build it. If you use the template's `forloop.first` you can control whether the first column is a `<th>`.

Comment: Let's forget about the `<th>` vs `<td>` hassle for a moment, and assume that I use a flat list and pass the number of columns as `width`. Then I would need something like `{% cycle '<tr><th>' (width-1)*'<td>' %}`. Does that exist?

Comment: No, but you might be able to use the `forloop.counter` to do what you need. I didn't give it much thought, because I agree with you that it's an insanely ugly solution. Do you have a problem with my answer building the table outside the template?

Comment: Building the table in the view was never my problem, but formatting the HTML with the Django templating language was and is. `forloop.first` was a good hint to get `<th>` vs `<td>` right. I think I have an actual solution now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Paulo Almeida for providing the two essential hints in his answer:

- The table — including labels — should be built in the view.
- `forloop.first` can be used to put the labels in `<th>`s.

```py
table = [
    ['', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Barf'],
    ['Spam', 101, 102, 103],
    ['Eggs', 201, 202, 203],
]
```

```html
<table>
    {% for row in table %}
        <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
            {% if forloop.first or forloop.parentloop.first %} <th> {% else %} <td> {% endif %}
                {{ cell }}
            {% if forloop.first or forloop.parentloop.first %} </th> {% else %} </td> {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I guess the answer to my implicit question — how the values of multidimensional arrays can be accessed from the template — is that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a good use case for [a feature request suggesting the use of iterables in the cycle tag](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5865). Then you could just `{% cycle rownames %}` in the first `<td>`.

Unfortunately, that's not possible, as far as I can see. I would take that logic away from the template and into the view (or, more likely, an utility function or model method, depending on the specifics), building a list that is easy to process in the template:

```
table = [
    ['Spam', 101, 102, 103],
    ['Eggs', 201, 202, 203],
]
```

The function to build the table might look like this:

```
def build_table(rownames, matrix):
    table = []
    for rowname, values in zip(rownames, matrix):
        row = [rowname]
        row.extend(values.tolist())
        table.append(row)
    return table
```